# Как динамически извлечь возвращаемый тип TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-типы

```
const isNull = (v:any) : v is null => v === null;

const isString = (v:any) : v is string => typeof v === 'string';

const or = <T extends Function,K extends Function>(fn1:T, fn2:K) => (first: any): first is ReturnType<T> | first is ReturnType<K>   => (fn1(first) || fn2(first))
```

Реализация

```
const conditon = or(isNull, isString);

condition(v)
```

Как из  `first is ReturnType<T> | first is ReturnType<K>`
получить не тип которые возвращают ф-ции а тип который задан   `v is null`

чтобы при передачи значения в описании ф-ции было `first is string | null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAJAlgZwDwBUB8UC8UAUBHALigEMA7EASiwzykShQCgB6ZqUSd4LKAJQmABXAE6kU4CEnjIEwYXFIBzNBlbsJXHgCMA9joA2EMo0bAATEQDejKLfWcYAN2L64AEx7SkpQQFstEMJQAD5QsvJKaDZ2AMY6pLJQzq5uRE4u7jw%20%20vokCCTkJnYMAKIAyihW0cW2cQnctNjZucT5ZCDVNXAAZrjJ7vgUVNY1o1B1icIQ%20di0rBPcUwhE4QqKIVA%20-oGdxQC%20UBD6CNAjY8ULUEs8c2yXS0Ttu3Z7na%20vpgAsVcUc0DA6ILYVCHAAewAgpDc%20S87TQAG0ALpoHAAOnR3SIKComAwKHhWwCwkRnUugLSgKyghyeQKHU6KHKlSgZ1GMX0rXyAFUTkFLFAPudLogeYEePhqFBaApZGQYhAdL1RcIqK1YIgkMqokL4olEGU5GtxY0MAByVZKU1YTDYP6KqWqmEai3KIpjS51NxwYDxHiAnAi3kAGjoCANEUUFDdbN1DSpNLVT3OPVwnu98UGw2eMfqV2mNyganu0xWhqUG2V2YFb0YeyAA)

> чтобы при передачи значения в описании ф-ции было `first is string | null`

смотри **t4**.

Реализация самих функций отсутствует - за рамками вопроса.

```
type $is<T> = (q: any) => q is T
// type tt = ReturnType<$is<string>> // type tt = boolean // : (

t2: {
    type $valid = $is<number | string>
    const valid: $valid = null as any

    TEST: {
        const q = null as any
        if (valid(q)) {
            const res = q //const res: string | number
        } else {
            const res = q // const res: any
        }
    }
}

t4: {
    type $or = <T extends $is<any>[]>(...f: T) => T[number]
    const or: $or = null as any

    TEST: {
        class User { }

        const isUser = (q => q instanceof User) as $is<User>
        const isString = (q => 'string' === typeof q) as $is<string>

        const conditon = or(isUser, isString)

        const q = null as any
        if (conditon(q)) {
            const res = q // const res: string | User
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

я нашел такой ответ

```
const or = <T extends Function,K extends Function>(fn1:T, fn2:K) =>
  <T>(first: any): first is T  => 
  (fn1(first) || fn2(first))
condition = (v:any): v is null|string => or(isNull, isString)(v)
condition(v)
```